# C++ non-direct Inclusion Scenario

Tags: c++

Ok, I have this scenario.

A class called a which includes windows.h.

```
#ifndef a.h
#define a.h

#include <windows.h>

class a
{
};
#endif
```

A class called b which includes windows.h.

```
#ifndef b.h
#define b.h

#include <windows.h>

class b
{
};
#endif
```

A main class as such.

```
  #include "a.h"
  #include "b.h"

  MAIN STUFF
```

The point I'd like to clarify is the following.

Because I am importing both a and b into main, I am concerned that windows.h is being included twice.  Is this so?  If so, how to fix?

Comment: Include them in their respective source files.

Comment: Classes don't include anything.

Comment: @Mahesh.  Yes, both class a and class be require windows.h because they use functions dependent on windows.h.

Comment: @user - Why not just include them in the source files.

Comment: @Mahesh.  What is the difference between including windows.h the a.h versus a.cpp file?

Comment: @Mahesh: Because his headers need access to some symbols from the WinAPI...?

Comment: @Tomalak - Yet in that case, place the header `windows.h` at the top level in the source file before including any other headers. Won't that solve the problem ?

Comment: @Mahesh: That's a horrendous thing to do. If a file needs a WinAPI symbol, it should include the WinAPI header. It should absolutely _not_ rely on something else that included it to also have previously included the WinAPI header. Headers should be self-sufficient. (Also, _what problem_? There is no problem here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#windows.h` should be (read: is) clever enough that this is not a problem.

- They use "header guards" to guarantee safety of multiple inclusion **within** a TU, the same way you did in your files `a.h` and `b.h` (though you should really pick better names for those guards... oh how easily they can conflict at present!).
- To guarantee safety of multiple inclusion **across** TUs (not your scenario at the moment), they restrict themselves to only allowing *declarations*, not definitions, in header files. The rest will go in the library binaries that are part of your operating system. (And, in fact, aside from template/inline function definitions, you should always stray from defining things in headers).

Comment: "they" = whoever wrote `windows.h`

Comment: So You're suggesting that I should #include <windows.h>
in the cpp file rather than the h file?  I didn't realize it mattered.

Comment: @user440297: Absolutely not. As my first line says, "this is not a problem". Leave your code as it is. Sorry if that wasn't clear...

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Just some lingering confusion from Mahesh's comment, but all is clear now.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the first two lines in your own header files.  Together, those lines make sure that the C preprocessor only includes each header file once.  This is the standard way headers should be written for C/C++ software.  Main system headers, like windows.h, do the same (or something similar) to make sure that the preprocessor only sees a file once.

Answer (score 2):

There *should* be no worries as the `windows.h` include file has guards in it.  If you do get errors, switch compiler versions or compilers in general.

Answer (score 2):

I'm 99% sure, that `windows.h` has include guards, so it *should be* totally safe to include `a.h` and `b.h` into one file - the things in `windows.h` will not be duplicated

Comment: If you're only 99% sure, then it's only 99% safe. :)

Comment: Well, I don't have `windows.h` in front of me, but I'd be very, totally, extremely surprised, if this is not like this (:

Comment: @Kiril: Sure, but considering something to be "totally safe" if you're only 99% sure is poor programming practice, no?

Comment: Right, I added "should be", ok (:. But if it's not, this would mean, that "windows" pulls the trigger when you include `windows.h` in your project( "Any language will let you shoot yourself in the foot. C++ will provide the gun, load the bullets, give you a drink to steady your hand, mount telescopic sights, and paint a large target on your foot" )

Comment: "poor programming practice" - ok, you should _always_ check everything, that you use, right. But are you trying to tell me, that you're always 100% sure for every single line, that you write in your code? Because I doubt it. (:

Comment: @Kiril: I didn't claim that I am!

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry, but I just took that personal - "poor programming practice".

Comment: @Kiril: I think you might have failed to spot the friendly poking that's been an undercurrent throughout this comment thread. :)

Answer (score 2):

windows.h is not getting included more than once.

indeed, c/c++ header files adopt the convention of protecting inclusion by means of an #ifdef guard block, like this:

```
#ifndef __WINDOWS_H__
#define __WINDOWS_H__
...
... <windows.h content>
...
#endif
```

so that the  is actually included just once

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but no worries as the start of windows.h is:

```
#ifndef _WINDOWS_
#define _WINDOWS_
```

As an aside, you might want to also

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

before the windows include, to keep out some of the more esoteric features.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be a problem because an important header file like `Windows.h` will also include a guard at the beginning like

```
#ifndef _WINDOWS_H
#define _WINDOWS_H

//...code

#endif // _WINDOWS_H
```

So the information in the `Windows.h` header file will only be included once for each compiled code module, even if the header is repeated multiple times, since after the first time it's included, `_WINDOWS_H` is defined, therefore the guards cause the preprocessor to skip the content of the remaining `Windows.h` files.